# How do I stop SQL Server converting 1900-01-01 to NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, smalldatetime

There seems to be lots of posts on how to convert `1900-01-01` to `NULL`, but my problem is the opposite. I have stored procedures processing `smalldatetime` (SQL Server 2008), but they keep converting `1900-01-01` to `NULL`, when I really want it to remain as `1900-01-01`. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code that reproduces this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, SQL Server can't differentiate.

`1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` is the *epoch* (zero point) for SQL Server's calendar. And if you say something like this in SQL Server:

```
select 'empty string',convert(datetime,'')
```

it's conversion algorithm doesn't throw an error, it converts the empty string to the SQL Server date/time value ... (you guessed it!) ... '1900-01-01 00.00.00.000'.

What happens with `null` values is dependent on the current setting of the SQL Server SET option `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`. If `off`, `null` values are essentially treated identically to empty strings.

As far as your stored procedure problem goes (stored procedure turning a date/time value of `1900-01-01` into `null`...that's a problem with your stored procedures. SQL Server won't automatically convert the non-null date/time value of `1900-01-01 00.00.00.000` to `null`: somebody is doing it explicitly.

And old versions of SQL Server tended to treat null and the empty string pretty much interchangably by default. I suspect your system has been around a long time.

As a result, SQL Server tends to have a hard time distinguishing an actual, non-null date/time value of `1900-01-01 00.00.00.000` from `''` and `null`

My suspicion, since you haven't shown us any code, is that your stored procedure has code somewhere that looks something like:

```
select some_date_time_column = case when t.some_date_time_column == '' then null else t.some_date_time_column end
from some_table t
```